# Extract arguments from stdout and pipe

Tags: linux, perl, unix, stdout, xargs

I was trying to execute a script n times with  a different file as argument each time using this:

```
ls /user/local/*.log | xargs script.pl
```

(script.pl accepts file name as argument)

But the script is executed only once. How to resolve this ? Am I not doing it correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ls /user/local/*.log | xargs -rn1 script.pl
```

I guess your script only expects one parameter, you need to tell xargs about that.

Passing -r helps if the input list would be empty

Note that something like the following is, in general, better:

```
 find /user/local/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.log' -print0 |
       xargs -0rn1 script.pl
```

It will handle quoting and directories safer.

---

To see what xargs actually executes use the `-t` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
for i in $(ls /usr/local/*.log)
do
  script.pl $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `ls` as this is often an alias on many systems. E.g. if your `ls` produces colored output, then this will not work:
    for i in `ls`; do ls $i;done

Rather, you can just let the shell expand the wildcard for you:
    for i in /usr/local/*.log; do script.pl $i; done